# Get python-like split() working with go's strings.Split()

Tags: go, split

In python, the `split()` function with no separator splits the on whitespace/tab etc. and returns a list with **all** spaces removed

```
>>> "string    with multiple      spaces".split()
['string', 'with', 'multiple', 'spaces']
```

How can I achieve something similar in `go`?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strings"

func main() {
    s := "string    with multiple      spaces"
    lst := strings.Split(s, " ")
    for k, v := range lst {
        fmt.Println(k,v)
    }
}
```

The above gives

```
0 string
1 
2 
3 
4 with
5 multiple
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11 spaces
```

I'd like to save each of the strings in `lst[0]`, `lst[1]`, `lst[2]` and `lst[3]`. Can this be done? Thanks

Comment: strings.SplitN(s, sep string, n int) []string

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for [`strings.Fields`](https://godoc.org/strings#Fields):

> ```
> func Fields(s string) []string
> ```
>
> Fields splits the string s around each instance of one or more consecutive white space characters, as defined by unicode.IsSpace, returning an array of substrings of s or an empty list if s contains only white space.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> fmt.Printf("Fields are: %q", strings.Fields("  foo bar  baz   "))
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Fields are: ["foo" "bar" "baz"]
> ```